# Could not obtain connection from data source

Tags: java, sql, mulesoft

I am trying to connect to the derby client Database using MulesSoft, i have followed  the given study material. Once I have made my generic connection and try to run the url error shows up stating: Could not obtain from data source.

Below the Error message i am facing

//////////////////////////////

```
org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionException: Could not obtain connection from data source
Caused by: org.mule.extension.db.api.exception.connection.ConnectionCreationException: Could not obtain connection from data source
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.extension.api.exception.ModuleException: java.sql.SQLException: Error trying to load driver:  org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver : Cannot load class ' org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver': [
     org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver, 
    Cannot load class ' org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver': [
    Class ' org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver' has no package mapping for region 'domain/default/app/tooling-application-8bc17c50-a618-11e9-a2eb-025041000101'., 
    Cannot load class ' org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver': [
    Class ' org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver' has no package mapping for region '/domain/default'., 
    Class ' org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver' not found in classloader for artifact 'container'.]]]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error trying to load driver:  org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver : Cannot load class ' org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver': [
     org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver, 
    Cannot load class ' org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver': [
    Class ' org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver' has no package mapping for region 'domain/default/app/tooling-application-8bc17c50-a618-11e9-a2eb-025041000101'., 
    Cannot load class ' org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver': [
    Class ' org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver' has no package mapping for region '/domain/default'., 
    Class ' org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver' not found in classloader for artifact 'container'.]]]
    at org.mule.extension.db.internal.domain.connection.JdbcConnectionFactory.createConnection(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:57)
    at org.mule.extension.db.internal.domain.connection.DbConnectionProvider.connect(DbConnectionProvider.java:139)
    at org.mule.extension.db.internal.domain.connection.DbConnectionProvider.connect(DbConnectionProvider.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor133.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.config.DefaultConnectionProviderObjectBuilder.lambda$null$0(DefaultConnectionProviderObjectBuilder.java:133)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.lambda$withContextClassLoader$9(ClassUtils.java:860)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ExceptionUtils.tryExpecting(ExceptionUtils.java:227)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:915)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:879)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:859)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.config.DefaultConnectionProviderObjectBuilder.lambda$applyConnectionProviderClassLoaderProxy$1(DefaultConnectionProviderObjectBuilder.java:131)
    at org.mule.runtime.api.connection.ConnectionProvider$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$e53e62df.connect(<generated>)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.ConnectionProviderWrapper.connect(ConnectionProviderWrapper.java:64)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.ErrorTypeHandlerConnectionProviderWrapper.connect(ErrorTypeHandlerConnectionProviderWrapper.java:64)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.ConnectionProviderWrapper.connect(ConnectionProviderWrapper.java:64)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionProviderWrapper.connect(DefaultConnectionProviderWrapper.java:51)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.NullConnectionManagementStrategy.getConnectionHandler(NullConnectionManagementStrategy.java:40)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionManager.getConnection(DefaultConnectionManager.java:241)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.DelegateConnectionManagerAdapter$EagerConnectionManagerAdapter.getConnection(DelegateConnectionManagerAdapter.java:160)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.DelegateConnectionManagerAdapter.getConnection(DelegateConnectionManagerAdapter.java:82)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.ExtensionResolvingContext.lambda$new$0(ExtensionResolvingContext.java:47)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.func.CheckedSupplier.get(CheckedSupplier.java:25)
    at org.mule.runtime.api.util.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:77)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.ExtensionResolvingContext.getConnection(ExtensionResolvingContext.java:71)
    at org.mule.extension.db.internal.domain.metadata.BaseDbMetadataResolver.getStatement(BaseDbMetadataResolver.java:48)
    at org.mule.extension.db.internal.domain.metadata.SelectMetadataResolver.getOutputType(SelectMetadataResolver.java:53)
    at org.mule.extension.db.internal.domain.metadata.SelectMetadataResolver.getOutputType(SelectMetadataResolver.java:27)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.metadata.MetadataOutputDelegate.getOutputMetadata(MetadataOutputDelegate.java:130)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.metadata.MetadataOutputDelegate.getOutputMetadataDescriptor(MetadataOutputDelegate.java:82)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.metadata.MetadataMediator.getMetadata(MetadataMediator.java:204)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.metadata.MetadataMediator.getMetadata(MetadataMediator.java:184)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.ExtensionComponent.lambda$null$13(ExtensionComponent.java:302)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ExceptionUtils.tryExpecting(ExceptionUtils.java:227)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:915)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:879)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.ExtensionComponent.lambda$getMetadata$14(ExtensionComponent.java:301)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.ExtensionComponent.runWithMetadataContext(ExtensionComponent.java:358)
    at org.mule.runtime.module.extension.internal.runtime.ExtensionComponent.getMetadata(ExtensionComponent.java:300)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.metadata.MuleMetadataService.lambda$getComponentMetadata$4(MuleMetadataService.java:185)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.metadata.MuleMetadataService.exceptionHandledMetadataFetch(MuleMetadataService.java:141)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.metadata.MuleMetadataService.getComponentMetadata(MuleMetadataService.java:184)
    at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.metadata.MuleMetadataService.getOperationMetadata(MuleMetadataService.java:83)
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.LazyMetadataService.lambda$getOperationMetadata$1(LazyMetadataService.java:67)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.LazyMetadataService.getOperationMetadata(LazyMetadataService.java:67)
    at com.mulesoft.agent.services.metadata.MuleAgentMetadataService.lambda$getOperationMetadata$2(MuleAgentMetadataService.java:74)
    at com.mulesoft.agent.services.metadata.MuleAgentMetadataService.withMetadataService(MuleAgentMetadataService.java:144)
    at com.mulesoft.agent.services.metadata.MuleAgentMetadataService.getOperationMetadata(MuleAgentMetadataService.java:74)
    at com.mulesoft.agent.external.handlers.metadata.MetadataRequestHandler.lambda$getOperationMetadata$3(MetadataRequestHandler.java:200)
    at com.mulesoft.agent.util.ResponseHelper.response(ResponseHelper.java:88)
    at com.mulesoft.agent.external.handlers.metadata.MetadataRequestHandler.getOperationMetadata(MetadataRequestHandler.java:198)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
    at com.mulesoft.agent.rest.RequestLoggingFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggingFilter.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1340)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1242)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:503)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the JDBC driver as a shared library in the POM?

https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/db/db-configure-connection#set-the-jdbc-driver

Comment: Yes I have done that, But the keep getting the same error.

Comment: Please share your pom and database configurations.

Comment: i Have managed to fix the issue, was just playing around with the Database and Pom and somehow managed to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Hey just in case someone comes across this error on my end I forgot to close the connection

```
finally {
        call.closeAll();
    }
```

this resulted to error="Could not get a connection from the data source ,
Adding multiple last resources is disallowed. Current resource is org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager$LocalXAResource@17d3bab6